# How to make @Service to be called by "new" operator?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

I'm creating an electronic diary app, using java spring, but I faced with a small problem. I decided to create role system with a state pattern. So the logic of this system should look like this:

1. In controller, after accepting request, it creates the object of context class.
   Constructor of context class gets concrete **RoleClass** in depends to user role.(it uses the factory)
2. In controller we call the method of context we want to be executed
3. In context we call the method of role we want to be executed.
4. In role class we call the method of service we want to be executed.

But here I faced with a problem. I have a context class, which creates an object of **UserService** class, which contains a lot of **@Autowired** fields. So what I decided to do is to add `@Service` annotation to context class and there I added `@Autowired` annotation on constructor of **UserContext** class.

However Spring autowires all the fields at the compilation stage, so there won't be any **UserPrincipal** in `SecurityContextHolder` when I start the program. So here I need to create an object of **UserContext** class at the request stage, in controller. That's why I added `@Configurable` annotation to **UserContext** class. But when **UserContext** class is creating, the autowired fields of **UserService** filing by null values.

So what can be a problem?

Btw I understand that it better to create a constructor of **UserService** class, which will accept all the parameters(such as **UserRepository**), but here are another problems:

1. I use **UserService** class a lot in other classes. For example I have a model, where I call this class. And here, after creating this object of class, the fields will be autowired automatically.

```java
@Getter @Setter
public class ClassGetModel {

    private long id;

    private int number;

    private char letter;

    private SchoolGetModel school;

    private List<UserGetModel> students;

    public static ClassGetModel toModel(ClassEntity schoolClass) {
        ClassGetModel model = new ClassGetModel();
        ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
        mapper.getConfiguration().setSkipNullEnabled(true);
        mapper.map(schoolClass, model);
        model.setSchool(SchoolGetModel.toModel(schoolClass.getSchool()));
        UserService userService = new UserService();
        model.setStudents(userService.convertToUserGetModelList(schoolClass.getStudents()));
        return model;
    }
}
```

And there is also a problem with the quantity of arguments of constructor. If my service has a lot of fields which is used in my program, I'd have to give all of them to this constructor, even in **RoleFactory**.

So here's my code:
**UserController**

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private UserContext userContext;

    @GetMapping("/marks")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getMarks() {
        try {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(userContext.getMarks());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
```

**UserContext**

```java
@Service @Configurable @Scope("prototype")
public class UserContext {

   @Autowired
    public UserContext(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }
    public List<HomeworkGetModel> getHomework() throws UserNotFoundException {
        UserRole userRole = RoleFactory.getUserRole(userService.getCurrentUser().getRole().getName());
        return userRole.getHomework();
    }

    public List<MarkGetModel> getMarks() throws UserNotFoundException {
        UserRole userRole = RoleFactory.getUserRole(userService.getCurrentUser().getRole().getName());
        return userRole.getMarks();
    }
}
```

**UserRole**

```java
public interface UserRole {
    default UserGetModel getUser(long id) throws UserNotFoundException {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    default List<UserGetModel> getAllUsers() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    default UserEntity updateUser(UserUpdateModel newUserData) throws UserNotFoundException {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    default UserEntity deleteUser() throws UserNotFoundException {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    default List<MarkGetModel> getMarks() throws UserNotFoundException {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    default List<MarkGetModel> getMarksByDate(String date) throws UserNotFoundException, ParseException {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    default List<MarkGetModel> getMarksBySubject(String subjectName) throws UserNotFoundException {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    default List<MarkGetModel> getMarksByDateAndSubject(DateAndSubjectModel dateAndSubject) throws UserNotFoundException, ParseException {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    default SubjectGetModel getSubject(long id) throws SubjectNotFoundException {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    default SubjectGetModel getSubject(String name) throws SubjectNotFoundException {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    default SchoolGetModel getSchoolById(long schoolId) throws SchoolNotFoundException {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    default SchoolGetModel getSchoolByNumber(int schoolNumber) throws SchoolNotFoundException {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    default List<SchoolGetModel> getSchools() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    default ClassGetModel getSchoolClass(ClassGetByNumberModel classData) throws com.diary.diary.exception.school_class.ClassNotFoundException, SchoolNotFoundException {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    default List<ClassGetModel> getClasses() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    default List<HomeworkGetModel> getHomework() throws UserNotFoundException {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    default List<HomeworkGetModel> getHomeworkByDate(String date) throws UserNotFoundException, ParseException {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    default List<HomeworkGetModel> getHomeworkBySubject(String subjectName) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    default ClassEntity addClass(ClassAddModel classData) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    default ClassEntity addUserToClass(AdminAddUserToClassModel userAndClassModel) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    default ClassEntity deleteClass(long id) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    default UserEntity removeUserFromClass(AdminRemoveUserFromClassModel userClassModel) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    default SchoolEntity addSchool(SchoolAddModel schoolData) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    default SchoolEntity deleteSchool(long id) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    default UserEntity removeUserFromSchool(AdminRemoveUserFromSchoolModel userSchoolModel) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    default SubjectEntity addSubject(SubjectAddModel subjectData) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    default SubjectEntity updateSubject(SubjectUpdateModel newSubjectModel) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    default SubjectEntity deleteSubject(SubjectDeleteModel subjectDeleteData) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    default TimetableEntity addTimetable(TimetableAddModel timetableData) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    default TimetableEntity updateTimetable(TimeTableUpdateModel newTimetableData) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    default TimetableEntity deleteTimetable(long id) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    default ClassEntity addTimetableToClass(TimetableClassModel timetableClass) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    default ClassEntity deleteTimetableFromClass(long classId) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**UserService**

```java
@Service @Configurable @Scope("prototype")
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;
    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepo;

    @Autowired
    private MarkMethods markMethods;

    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder
            = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserEntity user = userRepo.findByLogin(username);
        if(user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("user with such login not found");
        }
        SimpleGrantedAuthority userRole = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole().toString());
        return new User(Long.toString(user.getId()), user.getPassword(), List.of(userRole));
    }
    
    public UserGetModel getUser(long userID) throws UserNotFoundException {
        UserEntity user = userRepo.findById(userID)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException("no user with such id"));
        return convertUserToGetModel(user);
    }

    public UserEntity getCurrentUser() throws UserNotFoundException {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder
                .getContext().getAuthentication();
        if(authentication == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Long userId = Long.valueOf((String) authentication.getPrincipal());
        return userRepo.findById(userId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException("current user wasn't found"));
    }

    public List<MarkGetModel> getMarks() throws UserNotFoundException {
        checkUserRoleOrThrow(RoleNames.ADMIN, getCurrentUser());
        UserEntity student = getCurrentUser();
        return convertToMarkGetModelList(student.getMarks());
    }
```

If you know the way how it can be solved, please tell me. I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Don't `new` services. Inject them as method parameters or as constructor dependency.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is annotate the UserService class with @Scope and set the scope to request scope (see here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes).

Now whenever you request a bean, you will get a complete new instance (and at this point the security context is set).

So TLDR:

1. inject the UserService normally as a bean into your controller.
2. Annotate the UserService with @Scope as described above

Comment: Well, I added ```@Scope("prototype")``` annotation to **UserSrevice**, but my **UserContext** didn't update the role and that's why **userRole** field is always null. I also added @Scope annotation to **UserContext** but resullt was the same :/

Comment: are you injecting the UserService via @Autowire?

Comment: yep. I also inject userService via @Autowired in userContext. I updated my question with the new code

Comment: can you update the code? One thing i noticed is that you do @_Autowired private UserContext userContext; but also do new UserContext(userService);. This is not correct since you already have usercontext autowired. Why are you creating it again?

Comment: I updated the code.
I'm creating new ```UserContext(userService)``` because it doesn't update the **userRole** field in **UserContext** class. On the stage of compilation it fills null value, cuz UserPrinciple is not in SecurityContextHolder. So to update this field I decided to create new object.

Comment: Ok so in general the task is pretty clear: We want to execute some methods on the roles. One idea is to request a new role not in the constructor, but in the methods itself. So before you return the new value, you request the new role

Comment: Wellm yeah, thanks, but now **userService** is null again in **UserContext**. And now a can't even imagine what is wrong. I updated my question with the new code.

Comment: try removing the @scope annotation of your service.

Comment: nah, didn't work

Comment: It just says ```Cannot invoke "com.diary.diary.service.UserService.getMarks()" because "this.userService" is null```